# Angular JS - Laravel Concurrent http calls

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

I am creating a webapp for a friend using Laravel to provide a REST API and Angular JS as the front end.

I have a very strange issue...when a page starts up there are 4 $http get calls made, all along the lines of (but to different URLs):

```
this.getSiteText = function(resource) {
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $http.defaults.withCredentials = true;        
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: SettingsService.getPSMUrl() + "/sitetext/" + resource
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
    return promise;
},
```

On the Laravel side of things I am handling CORS in the filters.php file as follows:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    Log::info('Start Request'.$request->url());
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myfakeurl.com');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-    With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
});
```

I've tried multiple ways of handling cors however I'm now starting to think its not related to my problem.

So everything works on my windows box running xampp and then when I deploy to my hosting I start having issues. Randomly some of the http calls will fail. Fiddler shows them as 500's and Chrome's console outputs about the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error message...other times I just get a 500 in the chrome console. Weird thing is in Fiddler some of the 500's are actually accompanied by my JSON Data...so essentially everything is ok but the status code is a 500.

The other strange thing....If i drop back the number of calls to $http...so only request 2 on page open (just comment out the other service calls) then everything works perfectly...so my get call will reliably pass when on a page where only one other get calls is made...but fails if there are 4 on the page.

Any ideas as I'm out....I wondered if there is something wrong in Laravel where handling multiple requests at the same time hitting the database is causing them to get mixed up and fail? Is there an InstanceContextMode type thing with Laravel like there is with Microsoft's WCF and ASP.NET?

Any suggestions appreciated....my next step is to write a $http wrapper service in angular and timeout between each call :-(

Cheers Guys....hopefully I've given enough info here.

Comment: Removed Database calls and replaced with static text....same issue

Comment: Created a Laravel Service which queues requests and then only sends next request once previous one is finished....problem goes away. This will be my workaround for now however I don't like it as a 'solution'